# CKEditor: use ACF to filter source code

Tags: ckeditor, advanced-custom-fields

How can I enable filter to filtered (h1, h2, h3 tags) when CKEditor is in source mode? I used button which save content and close editor. If user use wysiwyge mode filter works, but when user switch editor to source mode and manually type H1, H2 etc. CKEditor won't filter this text (code).